# delete schemas with prefix

Tags: postgresql, database-schema

I want to delete all the schema within a database that starts with **'u_'**, for some reason, I keep getting over 200 schema created whenever I try to create and modify tables in **pgSQL**.

I tried using

```
drop schema u_* cascade;
```

but I don't think wildcards work like that (will get a syntax error code here). I know that I can get all the schema names through

```
select schema_name
from information_schema.schemata;
```

but from there on I don't know what to do. I just want to delete all the schema that are either empty or start with "u_".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This statement will drop all schemas whose names start with `u_` and their contents:

```
DO $$DECLARE
   s text;
BEGIN
   FOR s IN
      SELECT nspname FROM pg_namespace
         WHERE nspname LIKE 'u\_%'
   LOOP
      EXECUTE 'DROP SCHEMA "' || quote_ident(s) || '" CASCADE';
   END LOOP;
END;$$;
```

To drop all empty schemas, use

```
DO $$DECLARE
   s text;
BEGIN
   FOR s IN
      SELECT nspname FROM pg_namespace
         WHERE nspname NOT LIKE 'pg_%' AND nspname <> 'public'
   LOOP
      BEGIN
         EXECUTE 'DROP SCHEMA "' || quote_ident(s) || '"';
      EXCEPTION
         WHEN OTHERS THEN
            NULL;
      END;
   END LOOP;
END;$$;
```

But if I were you, I'd figure out what creates those schemas and stop it. PostgreSQL does no such thing by itself.

Comment: Hey man, thanks a lot :) yea I figured somewhere in my code I'm probably creating all those schemas, this is just a temporary solution before I fix the actual problem. The only hiccup I had was with `LIKE 'u\_%'` to escape the `_` character. I like how your code is easily readable.